Why is memory_order_relaxed not okay for a once_flag-like atomic_bool?
On slide 54 of Herb Sutter's talk on "atomic<> Weapons" (which unfortunately he didn't have time to present in the video), he suggests the following code is incorrect:
struct widget {
  static inline atomic<widget *> instance = nullptr;
  static inline atomic<bool> create = false;

  static widget *get_instance()
  {
    if (instance.load(memory_order_acquire) == nullptr) {
      if (!create.exchange(true, memory_order_relaxed)) // <- BAD?
        instance.store(new widget(), memory_order_release);
      else
        while (instance.load(memory_order_acquire) == nullptr)
          ;
    }
    return instance.load(memory_order_acquire);
  }
};

Supposedly the line labeled // <- BAD? should be:
      if (!create.exchange(true, memory_order_acquire)) // <- GOOD?

My question: what can go wrong with the BAD line (even on contrived pathological architectures that do not exist)?  Equivalently, what's wrong with the following argument for why the BAD line is actually okay?

If one or more threads call get_instance(), then exactly one thread will see false from create.exchange(...), so exactly one widget will be allocated and exactly one thread will ever store to instance.

No data races occur from access to the variables instance and create, since these are atomic regardless of memory order.

Because of write-write coherence, it is impossible for get_instance() to return nullptr or anything other than the result of the single execution of new widget().

Because the only non-nullptr store to instance uses release semantics, and all loads from instance use acquire semantics, all non-nullptr loads will synchronize with the store, meaning anything done in the widget constructor will happen before any accesses to the instance after get_instance() returns, so also no undefined behavior from accessing non-atomic contents of widget.



I don't think if makes sense to use acquire for that exchange. There are no other operations on create, so there is nothing that this acquire could synchronize-with. The whole idea of reasoning based on possible reorderings is rather flawed IMHO. The standard says nothing about how or when things can be reordered. The standard defines the (strictly) happens-before relation which in terms defines the observable behavior for concurrent execution. Any reorderings the compiler may perform are then result of applying the as-if rule.

With respect to this exchange, I would argue that this can be relaxed, because even a relaxed operation still guarantees atomicity. I.e., only one thread will ever see false returned. It is true that theoretically the compiler might be able to reorder parts of the widget creation before the exchange, but I don't see how this would affect the observable behavior. Or put in other words, if it does affect observable behavior, this is either a compiler bug, or there is some required synchronization missing (not part of the example) in which case we would probably need a different approach anyway

This wouldn't be the only case of Herb Sutter being overly conservative with memory_order in that talk, e.g. Why set the stop flag using `memory_order_seq_cst`, if you check it with `memory_order_relaxed`? .   Agreed with @mpoeter - the exchange just gives mutual exclusion, picking exactly one thread to do the new widget() and store the result.

The losers go to a spin-wait loop which does an acquire load, which could also be relaxed since there's an acquire load in the return statement. Or better load into a temporary and return it - even the fast path (long after construction) loads twice for no reason, once in the first if, once in the return.  And compilers currently won't optimize that: Can and does the compiler optimize out two atomic loads?
